# How to search for patterns in a list of strings without 100% similarity?

Tags: python, string, list

So I have a list of strings:

```
input_list=["ACTGATCTTATCGAGTCAGCTAGTCGATCGATCGACGCGCGATCGTGATG","TGCATCGATCGATGCTAGTCGATATACGCGATATGTACG","CATCGGATCGATCGATCAGCTCATAGTCAGTC","CATCGATCATATATCGAGCGACAGTCAGTCGATCAGTCATCAGGTAGC","CATCATATCGAGCAGTCATCGTAGTCATGATCGATCGAT","ACATGAATCGATCGATAATCGATCGCGATTCGATG"]
```

And a list of tuples containing patterns to be looked for in the strings.

```
list_patterns=[("AGTG","TCGC"),("TATC","ATGT"),("GCAT","TCAG")]
```

I have this function that, for each string, looks for (any) one of the pairs of patterns from "list_patterns". The first element of each tuple in "list_patterns" is searched for from the beggining of the strings, the second element of each tuple is searched for from the end of each string.
Subsequently, the function trims the string, appending the trimmed string to an empty list (if none of the pairs of patterns is found, it just appends the original untrimmed string).

```
trimmed_list = []
for el in input_list:
    for pat in list_patterns:
        beg = el.find(pat[0])
        end = el.rfind(pat[1])
        if(beg != -1 and end != -1):
            output_list.append(el[beg+len(pat[0]):end])
            break
    else:
        output_list.append(el)
```

The thing is, I want to trim and find the patterns, but not necessarily match only the ones that have 100% similarity. I want to also find the patterns that are somewhat similar (by a user-defined threshold) and trim the strings accordingly.

I found this function that retrieves the ratio of similarity between two strings, but I'm not able to implement it into my original function:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
```

As an example, let's say I had a string:

```
"ATGCATCGTACGTACGTACG"
```

And a tuple of patterns which may be slightly different from the original ones:

```
("AYTG","TARYCG")
```

Even thought the string does not contain exactly those patterns (but contains similar ones), I would still like to trim it (ATG | CATCGTACGTACG | TACG), and have an output:

```
"CATCGTACGTACG"
```

Is there an easy way to add the "SequenceMatcher" function to my user-defined function?
Thank you so much in advance for any answers.

Comment: Why should "ATG" and "TAGC" be trimmed? How does it correlate to the patterns "AYTG" and "TARYCG"?

Comment: Because in this case I consider them similar enough to "AYTG" and "TARYGC" to be trimmed. I know in this example it is pretty arbitrary, but that's why I wanted o establish a ratio of similarity with "SequenceMatcher", but I don't know how to incorporate it into my original function.

Comment: @tadeufontes Are near matches only allowed to be equal to or less than the input pattern? Or can they be longer, and, if so, how long? Also, I assume your real input patterns never contain letters outside the set `ATCG`? A few more realistic examples would help.

Comment: Yeah they could be longer or shorter than the input pattern. Currently I don't know how long, but I would establish a threshold of about 5 characters for this example.
Unfortunately my real input patterns contain letters outside ATCG, that's one of the reason why I have been asked to incorporate this "similarity threshold"

Comment: @tadeufontes Why can't you just remove the junk letters from the input patterns and search for whatever is left? Or does the target sequence contain junk letters as well? Your problem seems extremely ill-defined at present.

Comment: Yes the target sequence oftain contains these ambiguous letters as well. I'll try to clarify that in the text, thank you

Comment: If the string is FAYTGFFFF, the pattern is AYTG and the minimum similarity ratio is 0.75 then you will have a match on FAYT,  AYT,  FAYTG,  AYTG, YTG, AYTGF, YTGF and AYTGFF. How to choose from those matches. Should it be greedy or lazy? Or does the first and last letter in pattern need to match?

Comment: The first and last don't necessarily need to match, I think it could be lazy.
Basically I wanted a way to use the SequenceMatcher function in order to be able to freely  establish different ratios (and test them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom find function and call it instead of the string.find or string.rfind methods. This function just looks at string parts that has the same length as the pattern. If different lengths can match it has to be extended but it's hard to predict how much.

```
def find_similar(needle, haystack, backwards = False, min_diff_ratio = 0.75):
    n_len = len(needle)
    # create a range depending on direction
    if backwards:
        r = range(len(haystack)-n_len, -1, -1)
    else:
        r = range(len(haystack) - n_len)
    for i in r:
        # create a substring with same length as search string
        # at index
        substr = haystack[i:i + n_len]
        # Here we check for similarity using your function
        if similar(needle, substr) >= min_diff_ratio:
            return i
    return -1
```

Update your loop to this

```
trimmed_list = []
for el in input_list:
    for pat in list_patterns:
        beg = find_similar(pat[0], el)
        end = find_similar(pat[1], el, True)
        if(beg != -1 and end != -1):
            output_list.append(el[beg+len(pat[0]):end])
            break
    else:
        output_list.append(el)
```

Comment: Hey @Jolbas, can you update your answer with an explanation of what this code does? The goal is for the OP to walk away with an understanding, not just an answer. Furthermore, an explanation will greatly help others that come across this question.